# Computer Science: Workshop paper in top conference vs. Paper in mediocre conference?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, conference

What do you think would be the better choice prestige wise? Prof I'm working with gave me the choice to choose which to submit to. To be clear, the top conference is CVPR and the mediocre conference is a relatively new ACM conference.

I care about prestige because I'm applying to graduate school, and I want to make the best impression.

--Edit--

To clarify further, it's a short paper in the CVPR workshop which wouldn't go into the proceedings and rather would just be a poster.

Comment: AFAIK in CVPR whether a paper is accepted as a Poster or Oral is decided after review, and only differs in how you present at the conference. Both involve papers that are added to the official proceedings. So could you clarify what you mean by submitting a poster?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Sorry I didn't ask him too specifically, but he said we'd submit a short paper which wouldn't go into the proceedings so it'd essentially just be a poster presentation

Comment: Why do you suggest a "new" ACM conference would be mediocre? If posters aren't especially competitive, they have little value.

Comment: @Buffy Well new conferences are generally less well known. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "If posters aren't especially competitive, they have little value"

Comment: @Buffy For context, getting a paper accepted for poster presentation at CVPR is very competitive in practice (the overall paper acceptance rate for CVPR was around 22% this year as far as I know). Most CVPR papers are accepted for poster presentation.

Comment: @StackOverflowOfficial Did he definitely talk about a poster at CVPR, rather than a workshop paper? A poster paper in the main conference would appear in the proceedings. A workshop paper might not. The comparison between a CVPR workshop paper and a main conference paper at a weaker conference would be more nuanced also.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Sorry for the confusion. It's a short paper in the workshop. Long papers I know are included in the proceedings. Short papers I know are not

Comment: @StackOverflowOfficial In that case, I guess it depends on how weak the other conference is. CVPR workshops are seen as being less prestigious than the main conference, but they're still relatively high-profile compared to a conference no-one's ever heard of (the potential audience is fairly large). On the other hand, if the other conference isn't that weak, then a paper there might be better - it depends. See e.g. https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en&vq=eng_computervisionpatternrecognition.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz the conference definitely isn't on that list

Comment: @StackOverflowOfficial You're probably better off with CVPR-W in that case :)

Answer (score 5):

Both previous answers are misleading in this specific scenario, where the choice is between CVPR (main conference) and an ACM conference.

*Both conferences require submission of a full paper!* The only difference is that CVPR will decide after the review how your paper is presented, whether as long oral presentation, short oral presentation, or poster. Independent of this, all accepted CVPR papers will be published in the conference proceedings without mention of the presentation type. *You cannot submit your paper to both conferences*, this would be in breach of CVPR ethical guidelines, and likely ACM as well.

Regarding impact or prestige, nothing will currently (2020) beat an accepted paper at CVPR, no matter the type of presentation, if you are working in computer vision or deep learning related to computer vision. Having a CVPR paper under your belt would be great for graduate admissions.

That being said, on the flipside this also means that getting your work accepted in CVPR is likely to be much more difficult than to get it accepted at a normal conference. If this is your first submission to any conference, and you are doing most of the work yourself, then I'd wager your chances of getting accepted are in the range of 10-15% (If you submit an average paper that is written reasonably well, of course if your work is really outstanding, then disregard this rough estimate).

Comment: Both previous answers (one of them mine) consider the OP's question, if the OP hasn't described the situation in full, then they should edit

Comment: I agree. OP might not be aware of the specifics of the conference though. My answer is based on the info that the conferences are CVPR and an unspecified ACM conference.

Comment: The OP mentions in a comment that the poster option is a short paper that will not appear in the proceedings. But this answer seems correct since CVPR does not seem to have any option for submitting a short paper, at least in the main conference.

Comment: On the other hand, CVPR does have workshops, and papers in those might not end up in the proceedings.

Answer (score 0):

First, ACM is reputable and so the conferences they hold are reputable, even if new. The ACM is a valuable "brand" on a paper is a good thing for a CS academic. Some of the "new" conferences I once attended turned out to be major events and have had a long history. OOPSLA became SPLASH became ...

IEEE is also a valuable brand of course.

Second, a poster session may have a very large number of available slots and it might be limited only by the size of the room at the venue. So, it isn't especially difficult to get accepted, compared to a paper which will receive serious review and competes for a limited number of time/space slots.

So, if something (posters) is easier to do that something else (paper), the latter will have more "prestige" value. This is especially true if the poster material is not going to appear in the official proceedings and so is more ephemeral.

Maybe you can work it out to do both. Write the paper and write a separate poster presentation that talks about your work (and might even refer to the paper). Posters are better for building some interest in your *ongoing* work, especially when it is incomplete, and also for meeting people that might turn out to be collaborators in the future.

Comment: I don't understand. How exactly am I able to submit my project to two conferences? I thought this was not allowed

Comment: Don't submit the same thing, of course. Write a publishable paper for the conference. Write a project description for the poster session. They needn't be similar. It isn't the "project" that can't be submitted twice, it is the paper. The project can be described separately from any paper that arises from it. Some projects produce many papers.

Comment: @StackOverflowOfficial That may not always apply for venues that do not have formal proceedings. Many CS conferences allow submitting work that has not previously been published in an archival venue. Many workshops for instance are not archival, i.e. their papers do not go into any proceedings, so it is often permitted to submit to both the conference and the workshop simultaneously, or submit to a conference after presenting in the workshop.

Comment: @GoodDeeds + Buffy Interesting thanks, that's good to know and I'll bring it up. Do you think both a poster + paper on the same project would be any much more helpful for graduate admissions?

Comment: The paper is the big thing in this case.

Answer (score -4):

> poster in top conference vs. Paper in mediocre conference?

Credit for publications is significantly greater than credit for posters, so I'd suggest going for the paper (you could go for the poster too).

Comment: There's a big difference between a poster at a conference in another field, and getting your paper accepted for poster presentation at CVPR. The latter is a relatively high-value publication, just not one that's being presented via a talk at the conference. Conversely, there's much less value to having an accepted paper in a very weak conference.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz The OP questioned poster vs. paper, not peer-reviewed paper presented as a poster. The latter I've never heard of. Regardless, I don't recall ever seeing posters mentioned on a CV I've reviewed. Although this might be discipline dependent, I suspect that only those knowing the intricacies of CVPR will understand (and they'll surely consider a poster to be weaker than a paper), so I suspect a paper is still better.

Comment: @user2768 The latter is quite common in CS conferences. The best papers get a time slot to have an oral presentation. The rest are presented as posters in a poster session. Both however are formal publications that appear in the proceedings. While Oral papers are more prestigious, even getting a paper accepted as a poster presentation is very difficult in a conference like CVPR

Comment: @user2768 My understanding is that the OP questioned whether a "poster" (= a paper presented as a poster) at CVPR or a paper at a weak conference would be better. A "poster" at CVPR is a peer-reviewed full-length publication, and would be listed as such on a CV. This is indeed discipline-dependent, but I'd expect people hiring for academic jobs in the same discipline to understand. All other things being equal, a CVPR paper (whether presented as an oral, a spotlight or a poster) would normally be seen as more prestigious than a paper at a weak conference.

Comment: In essence: all other things being equal, a full-length paper at a weak conference isn't better than a full-length paper at a strong conference, and a CVPR "poster" is a full-length paper at a strong conference.

Comment: @GoodDeeds The OP has clarified it _wouldn't go into the proceedings and rather would just be a poster_.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz _a CVPR "poster" is a full-length paper_ The OP says it isn't. Anyhow, I'm not familiar with the field, so I won't comment further.

Comment: Actually, the OP clarifies it isn't even a CVPR submission, it is a submission to a CVPR workshop.

Comment: If it's a workshop submission, it may or may not end up in the proceedings (different workshops have different arrangements), and it may or may not be presented orally as well as just as a poster (ditto). It all depends on the workshop. Either way, the question was unclear, so I think we were just debating the wrong thing.